# Angular Datetimepicker: Template for directive 'uibTimepicker' must have exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use this library to implement dateTimePicker in AngularJS: [Angular-Datetimepicker](https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

I install the library with Bower, injected the module and I copy/pasted the example code.

Controller:

```
// Disable weekend selection
$scope.isDisabledDate = function(currentDate, mode) {
  return mode === 'day' && (currentDate.getDay() === 0 || currentDate.getDay() === 6);
};
```

View:

```
<datetimepicker ng-model="date" 
                date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
                date-options="dateOptions" 
                date-disabled="isDisabledDate(date, mode)">
</datetimepicker>
```

The problem is that the date field is empty and in the console I have those two errors:

```
angular.js:12520 Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'uibDatepicker' must have exactly one root element. uib/template/datepicker/datepicker.html

angular.js:12520 Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'uibDatepickerPopupWrap' must have exactly one root element. uib/template/datepicker/popup.html
```

UPDATE: this is the new html, I sourrounded the tag  with a  element:

```
    <div class='form-group'>
        <datetimepicker ng-model="appointment.date" 
        date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
        date-options="dateOptions" 
        date-disabled="isDisabledDate(date, mode)">
        </datetimepicker>
    </div>
```

The whole html of the form is the following:

```
<div ng-controller='createAppointmentCtrl'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label class="control-label">Select client</label>
                <select ng-model="appointment.customer" class='form-control'>
                    <option value='0'>New client</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="client in clients_list" value="{{client.id}}">{{client.name}} {{client.surname}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="appointment.customer == 0">
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input ng-model="appointment.name" type="text" placeholder="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label>Surname</label>
                    <input ng-model="appointment.surname" type="text" placeholder="surname" class='form-control'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label class='control-label'>Date</label><br>
            <!--<input ng-model="appointment.date" id="expiry" name="expiry" type="datetime-local" required><br>-->
            <datetimepicker ng-model="appointment.date" 
                date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
                date-options="dateOptions" 
                date-disabled="isDisabledDate(date, mode)">
            </datetimepicker>
            <label class='control-label'>Price</label>
            <input ng-model="appointment.price" type="number" placeholder="price" class='form-control'>

            <button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click="create(appointment)" style='margin-top: 25px'>Generate appointment</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="generated_link" style='margin-top: 25px'>
                <label class="control-label">Generated link</label>
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="{{ generated_link }}" class='form-control'>
            <div class="row">{{message}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put the datetimepicker into a div element such as <div><datetimepicker ng-model="date" 
                date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
                date-options="dateOptions" 
                date-disabled="isDisabledDate(date, mode)">
</datetimepicker></div>

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504748/angular-bootstrap-modal-dialog-wont-show-despite-seemingly-correct-call

Comment: Update question: I sourrounded <datetimepicker>  within a <div> element but nothing changed!

Comment: And you have `ui.bootstrap` included in your project with the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` file?

Comment: That was exactly the case! Thank you very much!

Comment: Added my answer for future readers, glad it worked out for you. Can't force ya to accept it by any means but if you want to it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from my comment:

Make sure to include the `ui.bootstrap` dependency in your application, as well as well as the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` file which includes the html templates for the directives themselves.